# angularjs - custom DropDownList how to set default value checked

Tags: html, angularjs

This is my HTML code.  It's a custom DropDownList that I made.  Can someone advise how I could set one of the options to be checked by default in this case below?

```
<div class="dropdownlistheader"  ng-click="toggle('subdiv','item')">
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="dropdownlistinput" value="{{selectedItemValuesDisplay}}" />
</div>
<div id="ddl123" ng-show="showItemOptions" class="dropdownlist">
    <div ng-show="showItemOptions" ng-repeat="option in ItemTypeDDL">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected[$index]" ng-click="toggleItemSelection(option.TypeID, option.TypeName)"> {{option.TypeName}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the limited details provided in the questions, I'll suggest the following:

```
<div id="ddl123" ng-show="showItemOptions" class="dropdownlist" ng-init="selected[0] = true">
    <div ng-show="showItemOptions" ng-repeat="option in ItemTypeDDL">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected[$index]" ng-click="toggleItemSelection(option.TypeID, option.TypeName)"> {{option.TypeName}}
    </div>
</div>
```

The `ngInit` directive will select the first element in the `selected` flags list, by setting the first index of the array to `true`